# Round robin with failover with Apache http client

Tags: java, apache, http

Looking the Apache HTTP components [HttpClientBuilder](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/httpclient/apidocs/org/apache/http/impl/client/HttpClientBuilder.html) and seeing that it has

- retry handler
- route planner
- backoff strategy

I am wondering whether these are intended and feasible to be combined into a **round-robin client-side load balancer with failover**. The [tutorial](https://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html#d5e351) for the route planner looks like pointing to arbitrary failover addresses is maybe not the intended usage.

Can someone shed some light on this? Would the load balancer be a supported use case or would I be bending the API too much and breaking it if I tried?

Comment: A HTTP client is not a DNS server ...

Comment: Linked URL broken (404)

Comment: If you are asking to build a reverse proxy with httpclient component, it seems this is conceptually normal, as an example you may check: https://github.com/mitre/HTTP-Proxy-Servlet and of course you can choose whichever load balancing strategy you wish to implement